# Why can't I install Microsoft Office 2007 in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am very new to Ubuntu and only just getting a hang of it, and my questions might sound stupid especially because I am a learner in terms of techie things as well.

So because of the nature of work where everyone uses stupid Windows and Microsoft, I need to have access to MS Office 2007/2010 as documents with too many tables or images open all haywire in Libre Office (which has otherwise been great!). I have been reading up about installing MS Office through WINE/PlayonLinux, but have been unsuccessful so far. I downloaded a MS Office 2007 package from Pirate Bay, which I extracted into a folder. I tried numerous different ways to install through WINE and PlayonLinux, but will discuss the one which seems to be getting me somewhere. http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/how-to-install-microsoft-office-2007-in.html ..... Initially, when I would click on the install button of MS Office, I get a message saying "The install location you selected does not have 1558MB free space. Free up space from the selected install location or choose a different install location". The install location in this case said "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office", which confused me as I don't have drives named as C, Z etc. I went to configure WINE and under the drives tab, created a drive named A with the path location /media/cd025f16-433b-4a90-abb6-bb7a025d0450/. Also the space thing is confusing as I have at least 450GB of unused space on my computer.

anyways, when I selected the A drive for installation, the installation starts, but soon I get the following error message, "Office cannot find Office.en-us\OfficeLR.Cab. Browse to a valid installation source" .... The part saying "OfficeLR.Cab" have said different things after the Office bit every time I have made an attempt. When I select the Office.en-us sub-folder or any other folder within the folder where MS Office 2007 is saved, it says "invalid source"!

I have been trying to get this sorted since 15hrs now (addictive!) and have learnt loads of things in the process, but have not managed to crack it. It might be something stupidly simple I am not aware off that is stopping it.

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks a lot.. Also I am still getting used to the language, so might have many questions

Also I am using Ubuntu 11.04 (tag 11.04). Also I think I don't have windows -- when my friend installed Ubuntu on my new laptop which had Windows 7, he was trying to keep windows in a separate partition, but something happened and windows was not there!

Looking forward to some support! Again thanks a lot

Comment: This forum is not really for help regarding **pirated non-free software**.  *Have you tried OpenOffice or LibreOffice instead?*

Comment: i.m.o. there's no need to downvote this question. Installing a legal copy of MS Office on a linux machine is perfectly legal. This question can be of interest for any user who has trouble doing this. The OP already stated he has good experiences with Libreoffice

Answer (score 4):

I have very good experiences with Codeweavers CrossOver. I use Office Word, Excell and Powerpoint regularly within my Ubuntu 12.04 system. Without any major problem. It works really well. You should give it a try. If you want to keep using it, you have to pay (once or a yearly small fee, I don't remember), but for me it's definitely worth the money.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/codeweavers-unleashes-new-windows-impersonator

http://www.codeweavers.com/products/#cxlinux/

Also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2000780

CrossOver also makes it easy to install any other Windows software, although most won't run flawlessly, but sometimes they do...