# Can I install Microsoft Office? If so, how?

Tags: software-installation, microsoft-office

I want to know how to install Microsoft Office (specifically, Microsoft Office 2010) in Ubuntu?

I am a die hard fan of MS Office and I want to know if there is a way I can use it in Ubuntu.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/275120/how-install-office-2010-under-wine-in-linux-ubuntu

Comment: See also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154005/why-cant-i-install-microsoft-office-2007-in-ubuntu-11-04/154018#154018

Comment: I recommend using LibreOffice. It's free, preinstalled with Ubuntu and it can handle MSOffice files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: @Jop LibreOffice is nice for most files, as is Google Sheets, but for more complicated files that are already in Excel format, it doesn't always do too well.

Answer (score 40):

Try [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/).

Note that the first few images are from myself, and the rest are from [here](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2012/03/install-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu.html) since I don't have a MS Office 2010 CD.

The following tutorial also works in Ubuntu 12.10.

Download PlayOnLinux using the commands:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O     
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

[image]

Click **Install**.

[image]

Search for the Microsoft Office version you want to install (in our case, it's **MS Office 2010**).

[image]

Click **Install**.

[image]

Click **Next**.

[image]

Choose **Other**. I'll assume that you have your MS Office 2010 CD.

[image]

Insert your CD and type `/media/cdrom` in the blank space. Replace `cdrom` with the name of the CD. Then click next and MS Office 2010 will be installed!

Although you can install MS Office, I recommend using LibreOffice (which is installed by default).  It's a free Office Suite that is compatible with all your office files.

Comment: Though one year has passed (and the menus of PlayOnLinux are slightly different now), the installation went smooth and is now kicking! I just had two bugs on POL related with Office OneNote and Outlook, though I specified that I didn't want them installed - so, no problem here.
Good job

Comment: Same here. Word works with Hebrew after changing Wine to latest version (http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-11298-Hebrew_Font_is_messed_up.html)

Comment: It seems only the 32-bits version of Office 2010 is supported, even if the machine is 64-bits. Can anyone confirm this please?

Answer (score 20):

Wine is a Windows application compatibility layer that allows you to run some Windows applications in Linux.

According to [Wine AppDB for MS Office 2010](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336), MS Office 2010 (32-bit) is given a Platinum rating, ie; it installs and runs flawlessly on an out-of-the-box Wine installation. Wine Version 1.5.13 or better is required for greater compatibility.

I have had much success getting office 2007 working, but nothing past that. I'd recommend taking a look into learning more about LibreOffice.

Comment: LibreOffice is just so limiting compared to the power that Excel especialy, but even Word and PowerPoint provide at this point.

Answer (score 10):

You may try using Wine (see Software Center) for Windows applications. Not sure if Office 2010 will work. Although Office 2003 works fine for me.

Comment: Microsoft Office 2007 works well too.
- http://bit.ly/igN2BC (English Tutorial)
- http://bit.ly/eaC4iM (German Tutorial)

Comment: Could you include the instructions to do so?

Answer (score 9):

I tried to install Office 2010 on my Ubuntu system. It crashed half way through. However, Office 2007 works without issues on the same settings. I suggest you try out Office 2007 . There is virtually no difference between the two. 
Mind you, MS Outlook and MS Access dont run on wine at all (atleast for me they fail to launch every time) . Only Word, Powerpoint , Excel and Publisher and Visio will work.

**UPDATE**:

I have managed to install office 2010 using playonlinux 4.0.16 on Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 1 64bit. Find the tutorial [here](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2012/03/install-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu.html)

Its as easy as installing it on Windows. 
See the screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 8):

A fallback option is to run an actual version of Windows under a virtualization system like [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page).  Of these, VirtualBox is the easiest to get running and to learn: just install the package `virtualbox-ose` with `aptitude`, Synaptic, etc.  It's a fairly standard GUI application.  Consult the [online manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) and/or [other documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/End-user_documentation) for further info.

Answer (score 5):

install playonlinux, fire up playonlinux and chose "other download software" on the left hand side, and select Office 2010 on the right hand side scroll list. After that it is pretty clear on how to install office 2010.  The install process takes a while so be patient.

Answer (score 5):

You can install [Playonlinux](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/playonlinux).[image] PlayOnLinux is a graphical front-end for the Wine software compatibility layer which aims to simplify the installation of Windows-based application.

If you have the CD, you can follow the instructions there. If you don't you can buy the CD [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/), you should also be able to buy the CD in the computer store nearest you.

[image: enter code here]

These components don't work :

- Microsoft Office Access
- Microsoft Office Groove
- Microsoft Office Outlook

Answer (score 5):

I am currently using Microsoft Office 2010 Professional and it works great, didnt have ANY problems installing or starting it up. Get this, it actually runs faster in linux than it did when i used to have windows on this box... i almost laughted my head right off.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and KDE 9.10.0, 32-bit (i386) all around. My Wine version is 1.5
I use the kubuntu backports for kde and the backports for wine as well just to keep updated.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120404053103/http://r00t2scari.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/how-to-install-microsoft-office-2010-on-ubuntu/) is one guide 
[image]

Or you can use [**crossover**](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/)

**Links**

1. http://www.linoob.com/2012/03/crossover-11-brings-microsoft-office-2010-on-ubuntu/
2. http://www.codeweavers.com/products/
3. [http://r00t2scari.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/how-to-install-microsoft-office-2010-on-ubuntu/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120404053103/http://r00t2scari.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/how-to-install-microsoft-office-2010-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 4):

**WINE OFFICE 2010 PRO PLUS**

*Install Guide for Ubuntu 14.04 x64*

Until recently, it was difficult of impossible to get all of Office 2010 running on Ubuntu.  I don't know about *ALL*, but I worked this out for myself and I have created the guide I wanted, but could not find.

I followed and updated steps from this guide
    http://www.unixwerk.eu/linux/slack/wine.html

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04, so Wine is 64 bit... which I don't understand, since XP is not 64 bit....  At any rate, I needed 32 bit Wine.

You also need a 32-bit Office 2010 ISO file.

**STEP 1)**
install WINE, WINETRICKS from Ubuntu software center
When I did this, I wound up with versions:

> wine1.6 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4
>
> winetricks 0.0+20140302-0ubuntu2

**STEP 2)** 
Create a wine prefix

> WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/wine32 winecfg

Note that I didn't want wine32 to be hidden (.wine32) ==> personal preference

**STEP 3)** 
Install fonts

> WINEPREFIX=~/wine32 winetricks corefonts
>   WINEPREFIX=~/wine32 winetricks allfonts

**STEP 4)** 
Install Dependencies for office 2010 (32 bit)

> WINEPREFIX=~/wine32 winetricks wininet riched30 vcrun2003 vcrun2005 vb3run

download and run script: http://winezeug.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install-addons.sh
Make executable: you need to right click-> properties-> Permissions --> Allow to execute (CHECK yes)

> ~/Downloads/install-addons.sh

**STEP 5)**

> WINEPREFIX=~/wine32 winecfg

-> Libraries -> add msi(native, builtin) 
-> select msi(native, builtin) -> Edit -> change to (builtin, native)

**STEP 6)** 
Right Click the ISO in file explorer --> Open With Disk Image Mounter

**STEP 7)** 
Run setup

> WINEPREFIX=~/wine32 wine "/media/user/Office2010 Plus/setup.exe"

(Note your ISO CD might not be named "Office2010 Plus", change as needed.)

**STEP 8)** WINEPREFIX=~/wine32 winecfg
-> Libraries -> add riched20

Now, under Libraries, you should have:

```
Existing overrides:
*atl80(native, builtin)
*msvcm80(native, builtin)
*msvcr80(native, builtin)
*riched30(native, builtin)
*vcomp(native, builtin)
*winenet(native, builtin)
msi(builtin, native)
riched20(native, builtin)
```

**STEP 9**) Create shortcuts
**9A)** use favorite text editor and create "WORD.desktop" on Desktop

```
[Desktop Entry] Version=1.0 
Name=WORD 2010 
Comment=Loads MS WORD 2010  Go go Ubuntu 
Exec=sh /home/user/Documents/DesktopShorts/word.sh  #you must use a shell script
Icon=/home/user/Documents/DesktopShorts/PNGs/word.png  #dl icons from images.google.com 
Terminal=false 
Type=Application 
Categories=Utility;Application;Office; 
Name[en_US]=WORD 2010
```

**9B)** use favorite text editor to create "word.sh"

> env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/wine32 wine "$HOME/wine32/drive_c/Program
>   Files/Microsoft Office/Office14/WINWORD.EXE"

**STEP 10)**
In file explorer, make WORD.desktop and word.sh executable

**STEP 11)** 
Copy these two files and make Excel, PowerPnt, OneNote, etc. as you desire.

**STEP 12)** 
Do not add anything to this WINEPREFIX=~/wine32.  Use a new WINEPREFIX for other programs.  You can break it, apparently.

**RESULTS**
Eveything I normally use works:

I use Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and OneNote on Linux.  Picture Manager seems to work, but shortcuts don't work, so you can't really open a picture.

Not tested, cuz I don't know what/how/details:  (I don't normally use these so I can't say *it works*)

```
BSCsync.exe 
GRAPH.exe 
GROOVE.exe 
INFOPATH.exe 
MSACCESS.exe 
MSOHTMED.exe 
MSOUC.exe 
MSTORDB.exe 
MSTORE.exe 
NAMECONTROLSERVER.exe 
ONENOTEM.exe 
OUTLOOK.exe --> reports are sketchy on getting this to work.  Check out guide at WineHQ [WineHQ: Outlook 2010][1] 
PPTICO.exe 
SCANPST.exe 
SELFCERT.exe 
SETLANG.exe 
WORDCONV.exe 
VPREVIEW.exe 
XLICONS.exe
```

**TIP on DUALBOOTING Windows 8**

You cannot access files on your Windows Partition if:

- Fastboot is turned on in PowerOptions --> Choose what power button does
- You hibernate or restart the computer and then boot to Ubuntu.  You MUST shut down for Ubuntu to be able to mount it properly.

For this reason, I moved my Documents folder to a separate partition so I could leave Fastboot on and Hibernate windows 8 if I want.

- To move your Documents folder, hit Windows+E to open file explorer.  On the left, at top, right click "Documents"-> Properties-> Move -> select a new folder on a new drive.  Windows will copy everything over for you.  This will include your Outlook.pst files, which are buried in some Application_Data subfolder.

Comment: great solution and horrible nightmare at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I got Xubuntu 14.04 and installed it via Wine first which failed miserably cause it was requiring MSXML 5.0...

When I installed it via [**PlayOnLinux**](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/), amazingly it worked perfectly, it even installed the missing MSXML 5.0 but gave me an error on Outlook.exe, so it only installed Word, Excel, PowerPoint and OneNote, the rest of them failed.

So, my advice is to install it via PlayOnLinux and not waste energy configuring Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but **Dropbox** lets you use Word, Excel, and Powerpoint for free with a personal account. See [the FAQ](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/microsoft-office-faq) for more details.