# how Microsoft Office 2010 work?

Tags: microsoft

Im new in using Ubuntu 10.14 as my laptop's OS. And I practically need MS Office 2010 for my study and work. Can someone give me step by step procedure to install the MS? Im also not familiar to wine. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the "step by step" ==> http://askubuntu.com/a/156299/9598 Good luck!