# Cannot install MS office 2007

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

When I install MS office 2007 through wine ( I followed the wine setting before), it detected a setup error:  A required Z:\media\USB\Office Enterprise 2007 DVD\Access.WW\OSETUP.DLL cannot be loaded. This may indicate that the file is missing or damaged.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to install Access? Access [won't work well](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25162) under wine. If you need the other stuff to run. [PlayOnLinux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156296/how-to-install-microsoft-office-in-ubuntu-12-04) is by far the easiest way.

Comment: I am sure you already know about this and have specific reasons for wanting to install office 2007 but in case someone comes here through google: 1. microsoft let you use their office programs online through a browser now (for a fee) 2. you can use libreoffice for free instead of microsoft office and it's fully linux + windows compatible

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to try installing through PlayOnLinux.

http://www.playonlinux.com/en/

I had success installing and using Office 2007 that way.

Comment: Since I have no Dvd rom in my computer, I tried to use usb installation, but it cannot work.

Comment: If you have an ISO file on the USB, I believe that PlayOnLinux can install from that. You would just need to mount the image.