# Prevent lost of highlighting of Microsoft Word documents?

Tags: software-recommendation

How can I open a MS Word .doc file in Ubuntu in a way that will preserve the highlighting done when it was created?  LibreOffice strips the highlighting when I load the files, and Google Docs will not open them at all.

Comment: You could try to install MS Word with [PlayOnLinux](http://askubuntu.com/a/156299/75166).

Comment: Have you tried the latest Libreoffice?

Comment: @Mitch LibreOffice is rather strange. I dumped it for MS Office / PoL

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. try kingsoft office i think it has no problem opening doc or docx files

also you can use office web apps. all you need is a live or hotmail account give it a try