# Office 2007 problems

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, microsoft-office

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit on a desktop pc.

However, I HATE libreoffice and had trouble with open office. I want to install Office 2007 enterprise. Every time I try to install it, Wine says that it encountered a serious error and needs to close. So, I put in a 32-bit wineprefix. Then, it kept saying "EnterpriserWWW/osetup.dll does not validate or is not present". So, I tried Playonlinux, and I kept getting the same error. How to I install office 2007 on my computer without these errors. I have wine 1.6.

I know it will work in some way because there are people who have done it, and I flawlessly installed it on a 32-bit Ubuntu pc.

Comment: It works on 32-bit? Could you create a new partition, install 32-bit Ubuntu, and install Office to there?

Comment: This seems to be a known problem with Office 2007, even on Windows. A quick [Google search](http://bit.ly/1uqoJQ6) pointed me to [two](http://bit.ly/1uqAWU8) [threads](http://bit.ly/1AbvszT) discussing this problem and sharing possible solutions.

Comment: Reading comments in [a related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156296/can-i-install-microsoft-office-if-so-how) it seems that MS Office 2007 works with Wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try WPS Office (http://www.wps.com) which has a UI similar to MS Office.  They have a Linux version; it is currently in alpha, but it seems to be quite polished.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) MS Office 2007 was tested for installation only - you may check there to see if there's something you're missing on that installation.  I note also that office 2010 and 2013 do not perform well under wine.

Two alternatives would be to use the [online versions of office](https://office.com/start/default.aspx) (which would be the 2013 version, but not Office 365) or to install Windows in a virtual machine, and run Office 2007 from there.

Comment: No, there is a free, but somewhat limited, version of [MS office online](https://office.com/start/default.aspx)