# How to Install office 2007 0r 2010 on Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: software-installation

Is it possible to install office 2007 0r 2010  on Ubuntu 14.04, I need to use it with Ubuntu as completely installed, don't want it as live or on-line or on-line app etc.

Comment: Office 365 is a web-based app. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry I thought it as latest version MSOffice.

Comment: sorry @muru I have rephrased my problem .

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/156299/158442

Comment: I installed Office 2010 with PlayOnLinux. It works pretty well actually.

Answer (score 0):

Some windows programs I still needed runs under VirtualBox-Windows. Easiest way, imho. Virtual machine with 2Gb RAM will be enough for office applications.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I don't want to opt for VM at !

Answer (score 0):

Better alternative will be to use an open-source package such as **OpenOffice** or **LibreOffice** for better performance. You wont get much with VirtualBox!

Comment: But i need MSoffice with open office and libraoffice as well