# Installing MS Office on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, microsoft-office, microsoft

I am a newbie on Ubuntu and I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop partition to test.

I would like to know how can I install Microsoft office (any version) on Ubuntu OS.

I have tried using playonlinux to install MS Office 2010 32-bit as instructed for other Ubuntu versions, but it failed to open and after I uninstalled and tried to reinstall, it is hanging at the installation process.

My plan is to use Ubuntu on my office laptop with MS Outlook for my emails as it is a prerequisite for the office. Apart from that I can use LibreOffice for my documents and workbooks.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use MS but have you tried `wine` or `VMWare` Windows install?

Comment: Pirated Windows software works best in a native Windows where the typical 'cracks' can be applied. Not so, most of the time, with any sort of emulation. Consider a dual boot or installing Virtualbox and create a Windows Virtual Machine for the purpose of running Windows software.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've followed the instructions available here: [Can I install Microsoft Office? If so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156296/can-i-install-microsoft-office-if-so-how)

If you tried that but it doesn't work, the first thing I'd recommend is trying to add a Microsoft Exchange account ("Settings"->"Online Accounts").
Secondly, you could run MS Outlook 2010 32-bit through [Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=34).
Finally, you could run it in a Windows virtual machine using `VirtualBox`.

If none of these works, maybe you should consider switching to [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/thunderbird). Just sayin'...

Comment: HI Celestin, switching to Thunderbird it not possible. I request a solution, it the link offered does not work. Thanks.

Comment: What about `Wine` or adding an online account, then? And a virtual machine?

Comment: I have tried with wine also. It did not work. I think I am not getting the right MS Office 32 bit torrent iso file. Any suggestions?

Comment: And have you tried adding a Microsoft account through "Settings"->"Online Accounts"?

Comment: @CélestinTaramarcaz Adding a MS account is a good idea but doesn't work for pirated software ;)

Comment: Thanks guys. It has failed. I have a licensed copy too but does not work.Decided to use windows. No other option. Much appreciated.