# PlayOnLinux is not showing content while installing application

Tags: windows, wine, playonlinux

I installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows. I liked Ubuntu and I have decided to switch to Ubuntu permanently. There are some Windows applications still I want to use for my Office work. I needed Adobe Premier Pro, Office 2010 on Ubuntu.

I have installed the latest version of PlayOnLinux 4.2.12 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. But when I try to install Office 2010 on PlayOnLinux a dialogue box appears but it does not shows any text or button to install Office. I have tried to reinstall PlayOnLinux for fixing issue but that does not worked.

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you need to stick to Office? LibreOffice should have most if not all your required functions. You can install it through the terminal via "sudo apt install libreoffice".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Microsoft Office? If so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156296/can-i-install-microsoft-office-if-so-how)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))