# Finding Practical Alternatives to MS Excel on Ubuntu for Educational Needs

Tags: alternative

Since I started using Ubuntu two years ago, I've grown fond of it and have no intention of returning to Windows. However, I encountered an issue related to my education. My teacher, for the subject of basic statistics, insists on using MS Excel for practical exams. I'm not inclined to switch back to Windows, so I'm wondering if there are any alternatives to MS Excel that I can use.I suggested using LibreOffice Calc or Google Sheets from the library, but my teacher mentioned that the functions might differ from what's needed in MS Excel. They strongly advised me to consider returning to Windows.Now, I'm faced with a dilemma. How can I effectively use Excel or are there any better alternatives available? I'm seeking guidance on this matter. Please help me.

Comment: If you're ok with Google Sheets, then why not office.com? I find it works with some sheets that LibreOffice, Google Sheets and Numbers had trouble with.

Comment: We don't know which all functions of Excel you are looking for, so ask your teacher about which all functions you need. Check whether they are present in LibreOffice Calc. You can also try ONLYOFFICE, and WPS Office for Linux, to check if those functions are present

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Microsoft Office? If so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156296/can-i-install-microsoft-office-if-so-how)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download the Office deb package for Ubuntu from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/microsoftonlineapps/files/v1.0.0/microsoft_online_apps.deb/download

Once the package is downloaded, open a terminal and run:

```
 cd /Downloads

 sudo dpkg -i microsoft_online_apps.deb
```